# When is painter's algorithm required with Z-buffer algorithm?

Tags: render, zbuffer

According to my teacher, in some situations, Z-buffer algorithm needs the painter's algorithm to render a 3D scene in a 2D image.

I thought Z-buffer algorithm as an extension, an enhancement of painter's one : for me, Z-buffer algorithm can do all what painter's one is able to do, and even more (intersection of polygons and cyclic overlaps).

However, in some situations, Z-buffer algorithm can't work correctly if painter's one isn't used... What are these situations ?

Answer (score 0):

At least one reason from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter's_algorithm)

> These and other flaws with the algorithm led to the development of Z-buffer techniques, which can be viewed as a development of the painter's algorithm, by resolving depth conflicts on a pixel-by-pixel basis, reducing the need for a depth-based rendering order. Even in such systems, a variant of the painter's algorithm is sometimes employed. As Z-buffer implementations generally rely on fixed-precision depth-buffer registers implemented in hardware, there is scope for visibility problems due to rounding error. These are overlaps or gaps at joints between polygons. **To avoid this, some graphics engine implementations "overrender", drawing the affected edges of both polygons in the order given by painter's algorithm.** This means that some pixels are actually drawn twice (as in the full painter's algorithm) but this happens on only small parts of the image and has a negligible performance effect.

Comment: "These are overlaps or gaps at joints between polygons. " : it makes me thinking at Z-fighting (overlaps at joints between 2 polygons), but it doesn't speak about this phenomenon nope ?

Answer (score 0):

The only situation I can imagine is when using transparency, because the Z-Buffer does not work when the transparency method used requires sorting. Imagine an upfront primitive already being drawn and the Z-Buffer being filled already, then primitives drawn later would be skipped. When drawing sorted, you can draw from back to front.